# Bound on eigenvalue of block matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $X \in R^{n \times n}$, $X \geq 0$ (positive semidefinite), which is partitioned as,

$$
       X = \begin{pmatrix}
        A & B  \\
        B^T & C \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Suppose I have the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$, and $C$. Can we lower bound the minimum non-zero eigenvalue of $X$ without having to solve the $O(n^3)$ SVD of $X$.